# How to deal with overflow in divide operator

Tags: javascript, operator-overloading, operators, decimal, divide

This is my problem: 
I have number as decimal like: var a = `0.5556`
I would like to multiply `a` with 86400: `var b = a * 86400 = 48003.84`; 
After that I would like to devide `b` with 86400: `var c = b / 86400 = 
0.5556018518518518`
The result of `c` is not equal with `a` value.
My questions is how to make `c`'s value equal with `a`'s value in javascript. Could someone help me resolve this.

Javascript

a = 0.5556;

b = a * 86400

Expected: c = b / 86400 = a

Comment: I want to precise result is equal `a` precise. I'm coding on `electron` platform, I had had try  `a.toPrecision()` but it dosen't work on this platform.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get a precise output up to certain number of digits after the decimal you can use [`toPrecision()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toPrecision) method.

```js
var a = 0.5556;
var b = (a * 86400).toPrecision(5);
var c = (b / 86400).toPrecision(5);

console.log(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are running into the limitations of fixing point representations, and arithmetic. Generally when you compare floating point numbers, you check to see if the two numbers are within a certain range of each other.

if you don't mind sacrificing efficiency, you could use a library to implement arbitrary precision floating point such as [enter link description here](https://github.com/MikeMcl/bignumber.js/blob/master/bignumber.js)